# Debug grid for libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Can I somehow draw a 3d grid in my libgdx app, so I can zoom in and out of this grid in order to see what is going on with my application?
For example, I'm trying to create a simple sphere, that should be in the middle of the screen, but it is not, and it is squished or somethig.

I want to know, where my camera is and what is the camera's view angle, all inside the scene. Here is the code, because stackoverflow asks for the code.

```
@Override
    public void create() {
        modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
        environment = new Environment();
        environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1f));
        environment.add(new DirectionalLight().set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 10f, 10f, 20f));

        cam = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        cam.position.set(150f, -9f, 200f);
        cam.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
        cam.near = 1f;
        cam.far = 300f;
        cam.update();


        ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
        model = modelBuilder.createSphere(120f, 120f, 120, 32, 32,
                new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.GREEN)),
                VertexAttributes.Usage.Position | VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal);
        instance = new ModelInstance(model);
        instance.transform.set(new Vector3(100, 100, 0), new Quaternion());
    }
```

Can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little bit of seraching, I found this amazing list of examples for libgdx, including grid with axis:

```
private void createAxes() {
        final float GRID_MIN = -viewPortWidth;
        final float GRID_MAX = viewPortWidth;
        final float GRID_STEP = viewPortWidth / 10;

        ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
        modelBuilder.begin();
        MeshPartBuilder builder = modelBuilder.part("grid", GL20.GL_LINES, Usage.Position | Usage.ColorUnpacked, new Material());
        builder.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        for (float t = GRID_MIN; t <= GRID_MAX; t += GRID_STEP) {
            builder.line(t, 0, GRID_MIN, t, 0, GRID_MAX);
            builder.line(GRID_MIN, 0, t, GRID_MAX, 0, t);
        }
        builder = modelBuilder.part("axes", GL20.GL_LINES, Usage.Position | Usage.ColorUnpacked, new Material());
        builder.setColor(Color.RED);
        builder.line(0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0);
        builder.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        builder.line(0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0);
        builder.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        builder.line(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100);
        Model axesModel = modelBuilder.end();
        models.add(axesModel);
        ModelInstance instance = new ModelInstance(axesModel);
        instances.add(instance);
    }
```

And here is an example how to use it: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/g3d/BaseG3dTest.java

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'createLineGrid' on `ModelBuilder` to create a grid that (unless you rotate it) extends in the **X-Z** plane.

For example:

```
grid = modelBuilder.createLineGrid(
   32, 32, 10.0f, 10.0f, 
    new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.RED)), 
    VertexAttributes.Usage.Position | VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal);

gridInstance = new ModelInstance(grid);
```

Where `grid` is a `Model` and `gridInstance` is a `ModelInstance`.
Then you just have to include a `render` call to your `ModelBatch`:

```
modelBatch.render(gridInstance);
```

Doing that on you code yields this render:

[image]

You can customize how many grid lines and their spacing to fit your need.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! I Found more detailed example in libgdx library. Although your answer is much smaller